# How do you change the time format on the X axis in Garfana Cloud?

Tags: charts

I know you can do it with the self-hosted Garfana by editing the config.ini files. How can I do this on Garfana Cloud?

[Garfana Time Series Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zwr2.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.